# How to translate "se respeta" on manta left in Mexico?

Tags: hispanoamérica

There is manta left by someone. The last 2 words i cant understand

[image: kkk]

The last words - la plaza tiene dueño y ***se respeta***.

"Is respected" or "respect that!" - what is the correct meaning?

Comment: I'm not an English speaker, but I don't know if it's correct to say "manta" here. In Spanish it corresponds to what we call a "lienzo" (_canvas_?).

Comment: @Rodrigo I think we would only use manta in English as a foreign word (except for the fish - manta ray). I think this is a _blanket_ in everyday English.

Comment: The town square has an owner and it must be respected. That would make it idiomatic in English.

Comment: @Lambie, now this is what  i expected! thx u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«La plaza tiene dueño» means that somebody "owns it", and people should not treat the place as if it is nobody's land. In some places «la plaza» is a name for the town square and in some other places it is an open market. In any case it is a place and the sign is stating that there is people declaring ownership, that are willing to defend it and enforce the rules.

«Se respeta» is an imperative statement meaning "it should be respected", better yet "it **has** to be respected". In other words, if you disrespect *la plaza* or disobey the rules stated above, you will get the capital punishment.

Comment: se respeta is imperative?? It's "pronominal".

Comment: @Lambie tu comentario es «gramaticalmente correcto» :) , pero a lo que me refiero es al sentido de orden, mandato o imposición de la frase. Sé que tu inglés es mejor que el mío y si hay una mejor manera de expresar eso, por favor edítalo. Gracias por la anotación.,

Comment: It is a passive verb: it should be respected [by you or whomever]. The thing is to make it idiomatic in English, one has to go beyond what is literal and make it: se debe de respetar. It's probably not the best Spanish, right?

Answer (score 3):

Antes que nada, dejo el link que encontré de [la noticia en donde aparece el anuncio](https://www.puntocritico.mx/2022/04/01/guardia-chilapa-plaza-tiene-dueno/). Esto ya nos da el contexto suficiente para entender el mensaje: es una suerte de 'demostración de poder' que se ha dado bajo un enfrentamiento entre bandas narcotraficantes. Quien dejó el aviso está tratando de ahuyentar a cualquier otra banda que intente ocupar la zona.

'La plaza tiene dueño' hace referencia justamente a que la plaza de la zona ya ha sido tomada por alguna banda como un símbolo de haber marcado territorio. 'Se respeta' es en este caso equivalente a 'debe respetarse eso', es una petición en sentido 'moral', hecha en particular con el propósito de desincentivar a otras bandas a que intenten disputar el territorio y hacer las típicas actividades pandilleras: traficar cristal (un tipo de droga), secuestrar, cobrar piso (es una especie de 'tributo' que cobran las bandas a los habitantes a cambio de 'protección') y robar. Quienes fueren encontrados haciendo algunas de estas cosas recibirán la 'pena capital'—perecer.

Answer (score -1):

Aunque el cartel parece que anuncia una declaración general de lo que esta prohibido en el pueblo o ciudad. La realidad era bien distinta.

Gracias al enlace que "*tac*" que aporta en su respuesta, la expresión"**Se respeta la plaza**", cobra un especial sentido, y aunque "plaza" puede significar "*lugar, pueblo o ciudad*", en este caso, donde se "obedecen unas normas", la pancarta lo que realmente señala es un aviso de una banda criminal a otra, advirtiendo que el territorio (*la plaza*), en este caso la ciudad o el pueblo de "*Chilapa*", esta bajo su control, es decir, ahora esa banda criminal *son los dueños de la plaza*.

En este sentido, y según La Guardia Nacional y el Ejército que fueron desplegados en la zona de Chilapa,  la violencia esta ligada a los grupos criminales Ardillos y Rojos por la lucha de mantener ese territorio de "*Chilapa*" bajo su respectivo control.

Como dato curioso de esa lucha por el control de la zona, la pancarta o aviso, apareció junto a seis cabeza cortadas, colocadas, sobre el techo de un vehículo, junto a sus cuerpos desmembrados que se encontraban en unas bolsas negras.